# Clustering biological sequences based on numeric values

Tags: r, bigdata, cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster several amino acid sequences of a fixed length (13) into K clusters based on the Atchley factors (5 numbers which represent each amino acid.

For example, I have an input vector of strings like the following:

```
  key <- HDMD::AAMetric.Atchley


sequences <- sapply(1:10000, function(x) paste(sapply(1:13, function (X) sample(rownames(key), 1)), collapse = ""))
```

However, my actual list of sequences is over 10^5 (specifying for need for computational efficiency).

I then convert these sequences into numeric vectors by the following:

```
  key <- HDMD::AAMetric.Atchley

  m1 <- key[strsplit(paste(sequences, collapse = ""), "")[[1]], ]
  p = 13
  output <-
    do.call(cbind, lapply(1:p, function(i)
      m1[seq(i, nrow(m1), by = p), ]))
```

I want to `output` (which is now 65 dimensional vectors) in an efficient way.

I was originally using Mini-batch kmeans, but I noticed the results were very inconsistent when I repeated. I need a consistent clustering approach.

I also was concerned about the curse of dimensionality, considering at 65 dimensions, Euclidean distance doesn't work.

Many high dimensional clustering algorithms I saw assume that outliers and noise exists in the data, but as these are biological sequences converted to numeric values, there is no noise or outlier.

In addition to this, feature selection will not work, as each of the properties of each amino acid and each amino acid are relevant in the biological context.

How would you recommend clustering these vectors?

Comment: Have you tried t-SNE?

Comment: tSNE takes extremely long to compute, and I have left it running on my i7-7700K for over 2 days with no output. Also, I have read that kmeans clustering on tSNE isn't a good idea. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263539/k-means-clustering-on-the-output-of-t-sne I need defined clusters for each row in `output` for future analysis, not just a visual representation. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask what do you intend to do with this further? I am doing something quite similar (also using Atchley's factors in a supervised task on peptide k-mers).

Comment: I am using clustering to reduce dimensionality then take k-mers from sequences from patients and classify them using SVM or xgboost or some supervised learning algorithm. Interesting that we have similar goals!

Comment: xgboost will eat 65 dimensions like cake, currently on my task which trains on 21 length kmers I get best performance with over 300 dimensions using xgboost (my total feature set has over 1300 dimensions). I also think feature selection can prove more useful in the long run then approximating all the features in a lower dimensional space. I understand all the AA attributes are important in a biological context but not all are important from a modeling perspective. For instance there is probably little involvement off Factor4 (CC): Codon Composition in determining the classes in your task.

Comment: I'm actually throwing frequency vectors into xgboost based on the frequency that each cluster appears in a patient. These vectors are of length of how many clusters exist. Another question I have is how to determine optimal number of clusters (maybe elbow method, but computationally heavy on this large dataset). My concern for dimensionality isn't xgboost but a clustering method. If I did feature selection, I risk not being able to generalize to another population from my understanding. Feature selection likely won't get it down to less than 30 dimensions (where Euclidian distance works) anywa

Comment: I think you're classifying k-mers themselves, whereas I'm classifying sets of k-mers (a whole patient).

Comment: The last comment is correct I am classifying the k-mers themselves, and I am beginning to understand your problem, unfortunately I do not have a recommendation. How many k-mers per patient approximately? Same number for each patient?

Comment: Approximately same, but I didn’t think it would matter as I am looking at frequency of clusters, and the cluster definition remains constant for all patients. Am I wrong about that? Thanks!

Comment: Give `SOMbrero` and `mclust` a try they might be useful. I am not sure how to answer your question, I think I would need days with your data just to get some idea(s).

Comment: My data is basically the same as shown above (for the clustering task, consider `sequences` as all sequences pooled from all patients). If you can think of something, I would really appreciate it if you could report it back here!

Comment: Have you considered clustering the k-mers based on a substitution matrix like BLOSUM or PAM?

Comment: @missuse Sorry for the late response - I have not. Are there any good examples you could point me to that utilize these algorithms for sequence clustering?

Comment: I do not think it's appropriate to talk about this in the comments. My e-mail is listed in my profile, send me a mail and we can discuss this further. Your problem seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think self organizing maps can be of help here - at least the implementation is quite fast so you will know soon enough if it is helpful or not:

using the data from the op along with:

```
rownames(output) <- 1:nrow(output)
colnames(output) <- make.names(colnames(output), unique = TRUE)

library(SOMbrero)
```

you define the number of cluster in advance

```
fit <- trainSOM(x.data=output , dimension = c(5, 5), nb.save = 10, maxit = 2000, 
               scaling="none", radius.type = "gaussian")
```

the nb.save is used as intermediate steps for further exploration how the training developed during the iterations:

```
plot(fit, what ="energy")
```

[image]

seems like more iterations is in order

check the frequency of clusters:

```
table(my.som$clustering)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25 
428 417 439 393 505 458 382 406 271 299 390 303 336 358 365 372 332 268 437 464 541 381 569 419 467
```

predict clusters based on new data:

```
predict(my.som, output[1:20,])
#output
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
19 12 11  8  9  1 11 13 14  5 18  2 22 21 23 22  4 14 24 12
```

check which variables were important for clustering:

```
summary(fit)
#part of output
Summary

      Class :  somRes 

      Self-Organizing Map object...
         online learning, type: numeric 
         5 x 5 grid with square topology
         neighbourhood type: gaussian 
         distance type: euclidean 

      Final energy     : 44.93509 
      Topographic error: 0.0053 

      ANOVA                : 

        Degrees of freedom :  24 

             F     pvalue significativity
pah      1.343 0.12156074                
pss      1.300 0.14868987                
ms      16.401 0.00000000             ***
cc       1.695 0.01827619               *
ec      17.853 0.00000000             ***
```

find optimal number of clusters:

```
plot(superClass(fit))
```

[image]

```
fit1 <- superClass(fit, k = 4)

summary(fit1)
#part of output
SOM Super Classes
     Initial number of clusters :  25 
     Number of super clusters   :  4 


  Frequency table
1 2 3 4 
6 9 4 6 

  Clustering
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 
 1  1  2  2  2  1  1  2  2  2  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  3  3  4  4  4 


  ANOVA

        Degrees of freedom :  3 

              F     pvalue significativity
pah       1.393 0.24277933                
pss       3.071 0.02664661               *
ms       19.007 0.00000000             ***
cc        2.906 0.03332672               *
ec       23.103 0.00000000             ***
```

Much more in this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SOMbrero/vignettes/doc-numericSOM.html)

Comment: Is there a reason you chose dimension = c(5, 5)?

Comment: @Jack Arnestad you can consider it a tuning parameter: from the help of the function: `dimension is approximately equal to the square root of the number of observations to be classified divided by 10 but it is never smaller than 5 or larger than 10.`